# MySQL Query For Copying Contents Into Another Field, Same Row

Tags: mysql

Is there a single query (subqueries in it are allowed) where I can copy the content of one field into another field, per row. Example:

price, and priceBackup

Records:

45.55

47.77

45.55 copies into priceBackup for that specific row,

47.77 copies into priceBackup for that specific row.

I do have a primary key, auto increment on it under 'id'.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Do you want to update the current rows or create new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 SET priceBackup = price
```

Add a WHERE clause if you only want to do this for some rows.

Answer (score 0):

update table blah set priceBackup=price;